# How do you fund an account on the testnet?

Tags: accounts, testnet

For testing purposes, how do you fund an account with the minimum required balance on the testnet?

Comment: Please use this faucet for getting TXLMs https://laboratory.stellar.org/#account-creator?network=test

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The **friendbot** takes care of funding accounts on the `testnet`. All you have to do is to send him your public key address.
You can do it manually via [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/)

`curl "https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/friendbot?addr=<your-public-key>"`

or just look at one of the code examples in the [official doc](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/get-started/create-account.html)

Comment: It does not work though. It currently gives an `op_underfunded` error code.

Answer (score 5):

Even though you can generate keypairs(The seed and the public key) for an account...it will have 0 lumens to start with.

For funding purposes, you can use the friendbot. It will add 10000 Test lumens which can be used for testing purposes on the test network.

[Stellar Friendbot Link](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#account-creator?network=test)

Answer (score 3):

there are many ways to do it

1. [here](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#account-creator?network=test) you can fund account directly with 10000 test xlm
2. https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/friendbot?addr=GAL4LACKK5PJ54XCJ2BR3RI6WKCTMDBFIC6LX4TB7PE2NLHE7Z6FW6Z6

copy and replace your public key  and hit the url in browser 10000 xlm will be issued to your public key

3. do this programmitically pair.publickey is the public key of account to be funded.

> ```
> var request = require('request');
> request.get({
>   url: 'https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/friendbot',
>   qs: { addr: pair.publicKey() },
>   json: true
> }, function (error, response, body) {
>   if (error || response.statusCode !== 200) {
>     console.error('ERROR!', error || body);
>   }
>   else {
>     console.log('SUCCESS! You have a new account :)\n', body);
>   }
> });
> ```